# SSH keys for Docker executor

Tags: docker, gitlab

I have created an image where I run some tasks.
I want to be able to push some files to a remote server that runs Windows Server 2022.

The `gitlab-runner` runs on an Ubuntu machine.
I managed to do that using shell executors. But now I want to do the same inside a docker container.

Using the following guide
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/#ssh-keys-when-using-the-docker-executor
I don't understand in which user I will create the keys.

In a shell executor case I used `gitlab-runner` user in which I created a pair of keys. I added the public key to the server that I want to push files to and it worked.

However, I added the same private key into the gitlab CI/CD variable as the guide suggests.
Then inside the job I added the following:

```
  before_script:
    - 'command -v ssh-agent >/dev/null || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
  script:
    - scp -P <port> myfile.txt username@ip:remote_path
```

But the job fails with errors

```
Host key verification failed.
lost connection
```

Should I use the same private key from `gitlab-runner` user?

PS: The `echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY"` works. I can see the key I added in the gitlab CI/CD variable.

Answer (score 0):

I used something similar in my CI process, works like a charm, I recall I've used some base64 formatted runner key due to some formatting errors:

```
- echo $GITLAB_RUNNER_SSH_KEY | base64 -d > $HOME/.ssh/runner_key
- chmod -R 600 ~/.ssh
- eval $(ssh-agent -s)
- ssh-add $HOME/.ssh/runner_key
```

Comment: I get the following error `/usr/bin/bash: line 119: /root/.ssh/runner_key: No such file or directory`

Comment: thats because you dont have the same enviroment as Ludwig does. you would use your `$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` insteaf of `/root/.ssh/runner_key` and make sure that you also have `$HOME`

Comment: The $HOME/.ssh directory must be created beforehand.